# No output after using PyCUDA

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, pycuda

I've installed `PyCUDA` using `pip`. I tried this in two computers.
One with a fresh install of `Python 3.7.1` and one with `Python 3.6.5`.

Everything fails after using `PuCUDA` with no error message.

> The minimum example is this:

```
import sys
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit # <-- Comment in order for `print` to work

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Print works')
    sys.stdout.write("Sys print works")
```

This doesn't print anything unless I remove `pycuda.autoinit`.

> Another example would be using `printf`:

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mod = SourceModule("""
        #include <stdio.h>

        __global__ void test() {
          printf("I am %d.%d\\n", threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y);
        }
        """)

    func = mod.get_function("test")
    func(block=(4, 4, 1))
```

This does not return any output also.

I think that CUDA fails but nothing gets reported.

My configuration:

> ```
> +--------------------+--------------------+
> |        PC1         |        PC2         |
> +--------------------+--------------------+
> | Python 3.6.5       | Python 3.7.1       |
> | Windows 10         | Windows 10         |
> | Cuda toolkit 9     | Cuda toolkit 10    |
> | GeForce GTX 1050   | GeForce GTX 1080   |
> | Visual Studio 2015 | Visual Studio 2015 |
> +--------------------+--------------------+
> ```

Drivers:

> ```
> GeForce Game Ready Driver
> Version        : 418.91 WHQL
> Release Date   : Wed Feb 13, 2019
> ```

I've noticed that this is a [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45788847/pycuda-cant-print-result) but there is no solution.

Comment: Did you try installing latest game ready Nvdia drivers instead of Microsoft drivers or whatever you had?

Comment: Yes, I have Game Ready Drivers installed and just updated from 417.22 to 418.91

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would help you out, but similar issue was solved by 
reinstall `cuda`(with `anoconda`).

In case you need it, you can install it via `conda` console

`conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit`

And to check if it runs well,

type `numba -s`

Hope this can help

Comment: Ohh, sorry, but could you upload the screenshot when you run       
    `$numba -s`
   Or any other error message/info please

Comment: I run the script outside of conda. I don't use Conda for this. But I can paste the report if you think its necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I hope this help you address the problem.

1. Check whether you've installed `CUDA` toolkit on your Windows.
2. Check whether `PATH` environments for `CUDA` is set properly.
3. If you are using the latest version of `VS`, it may be difficult(or impossible) for `PyCUDA` to work with it. So if you want to install an older version of `VS` additionally on your current system, after your installation, you may need to specify the path to your new (old-versioned) compiler.

For example, you can add this line into `compiler` function in `site-packages\pycuda\compiler.py`:

`options.extend(['-ccbin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe'])`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
1, 2) I have Cuda toolkit installed and properly set in the environment path. (Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130).
Also, I have edited the compile function and added options.extend... but again print didnt work

Comment: Also, I have Visual Studio 2015 installed